# Grails 2.0 plugin dependencies

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I'm trying to build a Grails 2.0 application using private plugins:

- mycompany-frontend = Grails Application
- mycompany-core = Grails plugins for domain classes

In the mycompany-core plugin, I created some domain classe and added a joda-time dependency in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
plugins {
    build(":tomcat:$grailsVersion",
          ":release:1.0.1",
          ":svn:1.0.2") {
        export = false
    }
    build(":joda-time:1.3.1")
}
```

in the mycompany-frontend app, I have the following BuildConfig.groovy:

```
plugins {
    runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":resources:1.1.5"
    build "mycompany:mycompany-core:0.1-SNAPSHOT"

build ":svn:1.0.2"
build ":spring-security-core:1.2.7"
    build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
}
```

I also removed grails.plugins entries from application.properties to avoid confusion.
But at the end, the mycompany-frontend cannot find the model classes from mycompany-core plugin.

What should I look/fix to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to define the dependency to your core-plugin as runtime-/compile-dependency instead of build?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I followed this advice http://www.nslms.com/2011/01/03/grails-plugin-dependencies/ (if I put every dependency in build+runtime+compile it seems to work but not a great solution) I was expecting the automatic import of joda-time in mycompany-frontend application because of the mycompany-core plugin definition

Comment: I moved to "compile" definition and everything works fine. Thanks